# attribute target to links

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to give links inside a specific paragraph a target. But I don't get this to work..

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
  $('.link a[@href^=""]')
    .attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

The links looks like this:

```
<p class="link"><a href="http://www.link.com">link</a></p>
```

Comment: `$('.link a[href$="link.com"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@attr` selector was dropped from jQuery plenty of versions ago (1.2 I think).

To find the anchors with an `href` attribute, use the [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('.link a[href]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `[@href]` (that is XPATH syntax).  Just `[href^=""]` will work.  However that's kind of a weird selector -- basically an `a` with an `href` that begins with empty string?  Do you mean `a[href]` or `a[href^="https"]`?